# What was the best method to count user total discussions?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I’m creating discussion forum. where I need to count each user total discussions. So that I’m thinking two methods to use as follow

Assume table `called` `user_forum_profile`

There has following fields

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qxZgL0v.png]

1 Method 
 Each time user create new discussions or comment other discussions update relevant total count on `user_forum_profile` table

Advantage

Total discussions could grab easily because `CountDiscussions` value will be equal to Total discussions

Disadvantage

Need to update every time when user create new discussion or add comment

2 Method

Assume table called discussion

There has filed called user id. When calculating total discussions, use count (user id) query to find total discussions

So my question is which method is best method? Which method using less server resources?

Comment: 2nd is a normal form. 1st one can be achieved better by triggers. I would go with 2nd.

Comment: I guess the 1st one would be better not to mention you can cache queries so it doesn't rerun every time.

Comment: 2nd is better I believe, there is no need to doing extra work every time till you need to read the count. Make sense :)

Comment: @avisheks
In vanilla forum they use first method...i also like use second method...that's why i need to fine best method. which consume less server resources

Answer (score 0):

From 2 method I prefer the first one.

My idea:

```
3. Method:
```

If your forum will be high traffic, can can use aggregate to process data.
You create a 1-2 new table, for example:

```
user_comment_aggregate (user_discuss_aggregate same table structure)
fields:

uca_id
uca_user_id
uca_datetime
```

Example values:

```
1, 123, '2014-02-26 07:08:09'
2, 123, '2014-02-26 07:11:22'
3, 123, '2014-02-26 07:22:33'
4, 456, '2014-02-26 07:33:44'
```

You just put a fast insert to this table with user_id and now();

Script process all rows at this table. 
For example how update post for 123 user and update profile:

```
UPDATE user_forum_profile SET CountComments= CountComments +3 WHERE user_id= 123
```

Then delete all processed data from that aggregated table.

**Advantage:**

- maybe the less user_forum_profile update, because only 1 times with all new post count

And you can process this table daily by server's cron script.
If you processing this at midnight or later and update CountDiscussions and CountComments

Maybe this can make a lowest server load, but...
**disadvantage:** 
post count not up-to-date every seconds, just daily (or when you run this script). Also, you can run this script in every hour or every 15 minutes, etc...

Comment: That would be good idea :)
but i'm like update data in real time....i thinking go with first method...because on Home page i need to show latest forum thread with total answers,when i use second method,it will already generate lot of queries